# Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

Tags: java, google-picker

Since last Feb 20th, while trying to access the Google Drive through Google Picker, i am getting the following error:

```
"Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)"
```

The application feature has been working since the beggining, and now it has stopped working.

Anyone can enlight me on this matter?

Thanks,

Comment: I've been getting it all day, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They now require OAuth tokens for everyone requesting Views that deal with user data.

Check this [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/tOF_Z0ePK1M), it contains the details and it helped in my case.